# ruby on rails Updating multiple partial when using ajax with form_remote_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to update more then one partial using the ajax form_remote_for helper

Currently I use this code which can update only one partial

```
form_remote_for :hour, @hour, :url =>{:action => "manage" },:id =>'hoursForm',:update=>'hoursIndex' do |f
```

I will appreciate if someone can tell me how can I adjust the update parameter so it can update more the one partial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to do this with the `:update` argument to `form_remote_for` I would suggest you use an RJS template for your `manage` action. If you need a refresher on this technique see [here](http://media.railscasts.com/videos/043_ajax_with_rjs.mov)